# React.js component doesn't work in Next.js builds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, babeljs, flashing

I'm trying to build a React accordion component as an [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accordie) package named [Accordie](https://github.com/ozgrozer/accordie).

It's working on Next.js development but not in production.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fb6x2) demo for development mode and here's a [Vercel](https://csb-fb6x2-du91sqjqq-ozgrozer.vercel.app/) demo for production mode.

Looks like this on CodeSandbox.

[image]

And looks like this on Vercel.

[image]

There's a flashing issue on production build. I have no idea about what to do. Probably something wrong with the build script.

I'm using Babel to transpile JSX files like this.

```json
"build": "rm -rf build && NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir build --copy-files",
```

And I need a general help about how to build a React component to be able to make it work in Next.js builds.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it has nothing to do with the build scripts.

I was using something like this. Exporting `<Panel>` and returning `<Panel>` inside the map.

```
const Panel = ({}) => {
  return (
    ...
  )
}

const Accordie = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, key) => {
        if (child.type.name !== 'Panel') return null

        return (
          <Panel
            ...
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

module.exports = {
  Panel,
  Accordie
}
```

Now just exporting an empty `<Panel>` and using `<PanelInner>` instead.

```
const Panel = () => null

const PanelInner = ({}) => {
  return (
    ...
  )
}

const Accordie = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((child, key) => {
        if (child.type.name !== 'Panel') return null

        return (
          <PanelInner
            ...
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

module.exports = {
  Panel,
  Accordie
}
```